# How can I improve(to take shorter time) my shell script code?? I am trying to seperate folder into several smaller folder

Tags: linux, macos, performance, shell, memory

I have been trying to seperate folder into several smaller folder. 
There is a maximum size for each folder and set files, files which has the same base name and different file extension, have to be together in the same folder.
[this is how result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g01HX.png)

```
echo -e "folder size limit: "
read file_max_amount

if [ $file_max_amount -le 5000 ]; then
    if [ $file_max_amount -lt 10 ]; then
        file_max_amount=10
    fi
else
    file_max_amount=5000
fi
folder_count=1
file_amount=0
folder_name='upload'$folder_count

file_name=(`find . -type f \( ! -iname "*.sh" -and ! -iname "*.bat" -and ! -iname ".*" \)`)

mkdir $folder_name

for file in ${file_name[@]}; do
  basename=`basename $file`
  name="${basename%.*}"
  set_files=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name $name".*" `)
  set_file_amount=${#set_files[@]}
  if [ $len -eq 0 ]; then
    continue

  else
    file_amount=`expr $file_amount + $set_file_amount`

    if [ $file_amount -gt $file_max_amount ]; then
      folder_count=`expr $folder_count + 1`
      folder_name='upload'$folder_count
      mkdir $folder_name
      file_amount=$set_file_amount
    fi

    for set_file in "${set_files[@]}"; do
      mv $set_file $folder_name
    done
  fi
done
```

This works, but it takes little bit longer when there is more than 10,000. It took 20 min for 20000 files for my laptop.
my colleague said it might be faster if I use memory not I/O. So I tried check set files using array, not `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name $name".*"`.
Like this.

```
echo -e "folder size limit: "
read file_max_amount

if [ $file_max_amount -le 5000 ]; then
    if [ $file_max_amount -lt 10 ]; then
        file_max_amount=10
    fi
else
    file_max_amount=5000
fi

folder_count=1
file_amount=0
folder_name='upload'$folder_count

file_name=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname "*.sh" -and ! -iname "*.bat" -and ! -iname ".*" \)`)

base_name_arr=()

mkdir $folder_name

for file_1 in ${file_name[@]}; do
  if [ ! -f $file_1 ]; then
    echo 1
    continue
  fi
  basename_1=`basename $file_1`
  name="${basename_1%.*}"
  arr=()
  count=0
  count_1=0
  for file_2 in ${file_name[@]}; do
    count_1=`expr $count_1 + 1`
    echo "1"$file_2
    basename_2=`basename $file_2`
    if [[ $basename_2 == $name"."* ]]; then
      count=`expr $count + 1`
      arr[$count]=$file_2
    fi

  done
  file_amount=`expr $file_amount + $count`
  if [ $file_amount -gt $file_max_amount ]; then
      folder_count=`expr $folder_count + 1`
      folder_name='upload'$folder_count
      mkdir $folder_name
      file_amount=$count
  fi
  for attr in ${arr[@]}; do
    mv $attr $folder_name
  done
done
```

But for god sake, it took more time than my first version...
So I need some help!!

Comment: Can you show a representative directory and file structure before and after the script has run? With very small numbers for file count etc., of course.

Comment: I suggest you remove irrelevant details from your question (aka. `if [ $file_max_amount -le 5000 ]`) and give the missing relevant details (aka. what parameters did you run with? what hardware are you using? what file system?).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I edited my post:)

Comment: @Veedrac First all the code after 
folder_count=1 
might be necessary for process, so you can ignore above it if you want and I don't run with any parameters. I am using Macbook air and I test with empty files which made just for testing, so it might take longer with real files that I need to deal with.

Comment: We still have to guess what the behaviour should be, based on code and a picture. Is it something like "I want to group files with the basename together and move them into a separate directory each; the name of the directory is `uploadX`, where `X` is an integer incremented for each group, starting at `1`."? If so, please update the question accordingly. And don't use a picture: show, as text, a few filenames and what the directory structure should look like after the script has been run.

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it is working code, but you want to improve performance; if you consider migrating, make sure to read what's [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there, and [what not to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: And to show the effect of `file_max_amount`, make it something like 3 and show what exactly happens if more than 3 files share the same basename.